# How much ethereum does one need for Proof of Stake?

Tags: casper

Is there a minimum to have in order to qualify for this proof of stake?

Answer (score 2):

Originally it was said to be about 1250 (https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/03/05/serenity-poc2/) but then the price of Ether started to rise and there was speculation that it would be set at 35 (EDIT: Currently plan is 32 minimum as per Mauve Paper - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1maFT3cpHvwn29gLvtY4WcQiI6kRbN_nbCf3JlgR3m_8/edit#) which is the last I heard. However to the best of my knowledge the actual amount isn't set in stone whilst they develop the final details. You can see the details on the latest specification on GitHub:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Proof-of-Stake-FAQ